# Hibernate recursive many-to-many association with the same entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, entity-relationship, hibernate-annotations

Another Hibernate question... :P

Using Hibernate's Annotations framework, I have a `User` entity. Each `User` can have a collection of friends: a Collection of other `User`s. However, I have not been able to figure out how to create a Many-to-Many association within the `User` class consisting of a list of `User`s (using a user-friends intermediate table).

Here's the User class and its annotations:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="uid")
    private Integer uid;

    ...

    @ManyToMany(
            cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE},
            targetEntity=org.beans.User.class
    )
    @JoinTable(
            name="tbl_friends",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="personId"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="friendId")
    )
    private List<User> friends;
}
```

The user-friend mapping table has only two columns, both of which are foreign keys to the `uid` column of the `tbl_users` table. The two columns are `personId` (which should map to the current user), and `friendId` (which specifies the id of the current user's friend).

The problem is, the "friends" field keeps coming out null, even though I've pre-populated the friends table such that all the users in the system are friends with all the other users. I've even tried switching the relationship to `@OneToMany`, and it still comes out null (though the Hibernate debug output shows a `SELECT * FROM tbl_friends WHERE personId = ? AND friendId = ?` query, but nothing else).

Any ideas as to how to populate this list? Thank you!

Answer (score 86, accepted):

@ManyToMany to self is rather confusing because the way you'd normally model this differs from the "Hibernate" way. Your problem is you're missing another collection.

Think of it this way - if you're mapping "author" / "book" as many-to-many, you need "authors" collection on Book and "books" collection on Author. In this case, your "User" entity represents both ends of a relationship; so you need "my friends" and "friend of" collections:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="tbl_friends",
 joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="personId"),
 inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="friendId")
)
private List<User> friends;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="tbl_friends",
 joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="friendId"),
 inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="personId")
)
private List<User> friendOf;
```

You can still use the same association table, but note that join / inverseJon columns are swapped on collections.

The "friends" and "friendOf" collections may or may not match (depending on whether your "friendship" is always mutual) and you don't have to expose them this way in your API, of course, but that's the way to map it in Hibernate.

Comment: I was hoping you'd come to my rescue for the third time :) It worked perfectly, and your explanation clears up my understanding of E-R significantly. Thank you very much, once again! :)

Comment: May i combine friends and friendOf? And if not, than i need help with jsonmanagedreference and jsonbackreference in one entity in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24563066/hibernate-user-and-friends-jsonreference

Comment: I'm using Hibernate 5 and one collection is enough - using two creates duplicated rows in tbl_friends.

Comment: How can I have unique constraint in "tbl_friends" using both "friendId" and "personId" ?

Comment: I think it's worth to add that, if using the same table, one of them should have a "mappedBy" and not have the `@JoinTable`.  _friendOf_ for instance: `@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "friends")`. Else hibernate will try to persist both and result in a `java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'x-y' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer seems overly complicated with the `@JoinTable` annotations. A slightly simpler implementation needs only a `mappedBy`. Using `mappedBy` indicates the owning `Entity`, or property, which should probably be the `referencesTo` since that would be considered the "friends". A `ManyToMany` relationship can create a very complicated graph. Using `mappedBy` makes the code as so:

```
@Entity
public class Recursion {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    // what entities does this entity reference?
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Recursion> referencesTo;
    // what entities is this entity referenced from?
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="referencesTo")
    private Set<Recursion> referencesFrom;
    public Recursion init() {
        referencesTo = new HashSet<>();
        return this;
    }
    // getters, setters
}
```

And to use it you need to consider the owning property is the `referencesTo`. You only need to put relationships in that property in order for them to be referenced. When you read an `Entity` back, assuming you do a `fetch join`, JPA will create the collections for the result. When you delete an Entity, JPA will delete all the references to it.

```
tx.begin();
Recursion r0 = new Recursion().init();
Recursion r1 = new Recursion().init();
Recursion r2 = new Recursion().init();
r0.getReferencesTo().add(r1);
r1.getReferencesTo().add(r2);
em.persist(r0);
em.persist(r1);
em.persist(r2);

tx.commit();
// required so that existing entities with null referencesFrom will be removed from cache.
em.clear();
for ( int i=1; i <= 3; ++i ) {
    Recursion r = em.createQuery("select distinct r from Recursion r left join fetch r.referencesTo left join fetch r.referencesFrom where id = :id", Recursion.class).setParameter("id",  i).getSingleResult();
    System.out.println(r + " To=" + Arrays.toString(r.getReferencesTo().toArray()) + " From=" + Arrays.toString(r.getReferencesFrom().toArray()) );
}
tx.begin();
em.createQuery("delete from Recursion where id = 2").executeUpdate();
tx.commit();
// required so that existing entities with referencesTo will be removed from cache.
em.clear();
Recursion r = em.createQuery("select distinct r from Recursion r left join fetch r.referencesTo left join fetch r.referencesFrom where id = :id", Recursion.class).setParameter("id",  1).getSingleResult();
System.out.println(r + " To=" + Arrays.toString(r.getReferencesTo().toArray()) + " From=" + Arrays.toString(r.getReferencesFrom().toArray()) );
```

Which gives the following log output (always check the generated SQL statements):

```
Hibernate: create table Recursion (id integer not null, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table Recursion_Recursion (referencesFrom_id integer not null, referencesTo_id integer not null, primary key (referencesFrom_id, referencesTo_id))
Hibernate: create sequence hibernate_sequence start with 1 increment by 1
Hibernate: alter table Recursion_Recursion add constraint FKsi0wfuwfs0bl19jjpofw4n8pt foreign key (referencesTo_id) references Recursion
Hibernate: alter table Recursion_Recursion add constraint FKarrkuyh2v1j5qnlui2vbpl7tk foreign key (referencesFrom_id) references Recursion
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: insert into Recursion (id) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into Recursion (id) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into Recursion (id) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into Recursion_Recursion (referencesFrom_id, referencesTo_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Recursion_Recursion (referencesFrom_id, referencesTo_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: select distinct recursion0_.id as id1_2_0_, recursion2_.id as id1_2_1_, recursion4_.id as id1_2_2_, references1_.referencesFrom_id as referenc1_3_0__, references1_.referencesTo_id as referenc2_3_0__, references3_.referencesTo_id as referenc2_3_1__, references3_.referencesFrom_id as referenc1_3_1__ from Recursion recursion0_ left outer join Recursion_Recursion references1_ on recursion0_.id=references1_.referencesFrom_id left outer join Recursion recursion2_ on references1_.referencesTo_id=recursion2_.id left outer join Recursion_Recursion references3_ on recursion0_.id=references3_.referencesTo_id left outer join Recursion recursion4_ on references3_.referencesFrom_id=recursion4_.id where id=?
model.Recursion@7bdf6bb7 To=[model.Recursion@1bc53649] From=[]
Hibernate: select distinct recursion0_.id as id1_2_0_, recursion2_.id as id1_2_1_, recursion4_.id as id1_2_2_, references1_.referencesFrom_id as referenc1_3_0__, references1_.referencesTo_id as referenc2_3_0__, references3_.referencesTo_id as referenc2_3_1__, references3_.referencesFrom_id as referenc1_3_1__ from Recursion recursion0_ left outer join Recursion_Recursion references1_ on recursion0_.id=references1_.referencesFrom_id left outer join Recursion recursion2_ on references1_.referencesTo_id=recursion2_.id left outer join Recursion_Recursion references3_ on recursion0_.id=references3_.referencesTo_id left outer join Recursion recursion4_ on references3_.referencesFrom_id=recursion4_.id where id=?
model.Recursion@1bc53649 To=[model.Recursion@42deb43a] From=[model.Recursion@7bdf6bb7]
Hibernate: select distinct recursion0_.id as id1_2_0_, recursion2_.id as id1_2_1_, recursion4_.id as id1_2_2_, references1_.referencesFrom_id as referenc1_3_0__, references1_.referencesTo_id as referenc2_3_0__, references3_.referencesTo_id as referenc2_3_1__, references3_.referencesFrom_id as referenc1_3_1__ from Recursion recursion0_ left outer join Recursion_Recursion references1_ on recursion0_.id=references1_.referencesFrom_id left outer join Recursion recursion2_ on references1_.referencesTo_id=recursion2_.id left outer join Recursion_Recursion references3_ on recursion0_.id=references3_.referencesTo_id left outer join Recursion recursion4_ on references3_.referencesFrom_id=recursion4_.id where id=?
model.Recursion@42deb43a To=[] From=[model.Recursion@1bc53649]
Hibernate: delete from Recursion_Recursion where (referencesTo_id) in (select id from Recursion where id=2)
Hibernate: delete from Recursion_Recursion where (referencesFrom_id) in (select id from Recursion where id=2)
Hibernate: delete from Recursion where id=2
Hibernate: select distinct recursion0_.id as id1_2_0_, recursion2_.id as id1_2_1_, recursion4_.id as id1_2_2_, references1_.referencesFrom_id as referenc1_3_0__, references1_.referencesTo_id as referenc2_3_0__, references3_.referencesTo_id as referenc2_3_1__, references3_.referencesFrom_id as referenc1_3_1__ from Recursion recursion0_ left outer join Recursion_Recursion references1_ on recursion0_.id=references1_.referencesFrom_id left outer join Recursion recursion2_ on references1_.referencesTo_id=recursion2_.id left outer join Recursion_Recursion references3_ on recursion0_.id=references3_.referencesTo_id left outer join Recursion recursion4_ on references3_.referencesFrom_id=recursion4_.id where id=?
model.Recursion@6b739528 To=[] From=[]
```

Comment: This answer should be the accepted one, simple 1 parameter solution. It creates exactly what you would expect in a directed graph. A unique relationship table representing edges from a to b, avoiding duplicate information in separate columns.

Answer (score 0):

Actually its very simple and could be achieved by following say you have following entity

```
public class Human {
    int id;
    short age;
    String name;
    List<Human> relatives;



    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public short getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(short age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public List<Human> getRelatives() {
        return relatives;
    }
    public void setRelatives(List<Human> relatives) {
        this.relatives = relatives;
    }

    public void addRelative(Human relative){
        if(relatives == null)
            relatives = new ArrayList<Human>();
        relatives.add(relative);
    }




}
```

HBM for same:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="org.know.july31.hb.Human" table="Human">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="H_ID" />
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="age" type="short">
            <column name="age" />
        </property>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="NAME" length="200"/>
        </property>
        <list name="relatives" table="relatives" cascade="all">
         <key column="H_ID"/>
         <index column="U_ID"/>
         <many-to-many class="org.know.july31.hb.Human" column="relation"/>
      </list>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And test case

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.know.common.HBUtil;
import org.know.july31.hb.Human;

public class SimpleTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Human h1 = new Human();
        short s = 23;
        h1.setAge(s);
        h1.setName("Ratnesh Kumar singh");
        Human h2 = new Human();
        h2.setAge(s);
        h2.setName("Praveen Kumar singh");
        h1.addRelative(h2);
        Human h3 = new Human();
        h3.setAge(s);
        h3.setName("Sumit Kumar singh");
        h2.addRelative(h3);
        Human dk = new Human();
        dk.setAge(s);
        dk.setName("D Kumar singh");
        h3.addRelative(dk);
        HBUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
        HBUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().save(h1);
        HBUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
        HBUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
        h1 = (Human)HBUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().load(Human.class, 1);
        System.out.println(h1.getRelatives().get(0).getName());

        HBUtil.shutdown();
    }

}
```