# Hibernate many to many mapping the same entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

When I am mapping the same entity like was answered here :

[Hibernate many-to-many association with the same entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656113/hibernate-many-to-many-association-with-the-same-entity)

in "tbl_friends" table I have rows with the same meaning. For example, I have User with id=1 and User with id=2. In "tbl_friends" table when they are linked as friends I have two rows

```
1-2
2-1
```

Is it posible somehow make this kind of relationship in one row (1-2 or 2-1) using Hibernate or JPA anotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't because those 2 rows doesn't have the same meaning. One row is saying that PersonA is friend with PersonB and the other that PersonB is friend with PersonA. Functionnally speaking, in your example, those 2 relations might have the same meaning but that's not the case at the database level (friendship is not always mutual ... that's sad). The only thing you can do is hide it in your API :

```
public class Person {

   private Set<Person> friends = new HashSet<Person>();

   public void addFriend(Person person) {
      friends.add(person);
      person.getFriends().add(this);
   }
}
```

Comment: if there are hundreds of data, getFriends() will take too much time. How can we optimize it?