# Hibernate User and Friends JsonReference

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jackson

I have got two tables: Users and User_Friend for showing relations with addition fields.

```
CREATE TABLE public.users
(
  uuid              VARCHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY                     NOT NULL,
  username          VARCHAR(45) UNIQUE                          NOT NULL,
  first_name        VARCHAR(255)                                NOT NULL,
  last_name         VARCHAR(255),
  middle_name       VARCHAR(255)
);



CREATE TABLE public.user_friends
(
  uuid          VARCHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY,
  user_uuid     VARCHAR(36) REFERENCES public.users (uuid) NOT NULL,
  friend_uuid   VARCHAR(36) REFERENCES public.users (uuid) NOT NULL,
  friendAddDate TIMESTAMP                                  NOT NULL,
  friendTypeId  INT                                        NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT friend_unique UNIQUE (user_uuid, friend_uuid)
);
```

Java entities with hibernate annotations:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid", strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "uuid", unique = true)
    protected String uuid;

    @Column(name = "username")
    protected String username;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<UserFriend> userFriends = new HashSet<>();

@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "friendUser", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<UserFriend> userFriendOf = new HashSet<>();

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_friends")
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "user",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_uuid")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "friendUser",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "friend_uuid")) })
public class UserFriend implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "uuid", unique = true)
    protected String uuid;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_uuid")
    private User user;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_uuid")
    private User friendUser;

    @Column(name = "friendadddate")
    protected Date friendAddDate;

    @Column(name = "friendtypeid")
    protected int friendTypeId;
}
```

I'm trying to solve problem with recursion while deserialisation into JSON i've add @JsonManagedReference to Set of userFriends and userFriendOf of User class and @JsonBackReference to user and friendUser entities of UserFriend class and now in JSON on JSP i have not fields nor friendUser nor user.

But in this case - without Set friendsOf in class User in JSON i can user friendUser of UserFriend class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid", strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "uuid", unique = true)
    protected String uuid;

    @Column(name = "username")
    protected String username;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<UserFriend> userFriends = new HashSet<>();

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_friends")
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "user",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_uuid")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "friendUser",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "friend_uuid")) })
public class UserFriend implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "uuid", unique = true)
    protected String uuid;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_uuid")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_uuid")
    private User friendUser;

    @Column(name = "friendadddate")
    protected Date friendAddDate;

    @Column(name = "friendtypeid")
    protected int friendTypeId;
}
```

So my question is what i have to do to get friendUser and user in all Sets of User class?

Update progress:
I'm googling information about my question and two days in a row first(second) link in google - this question... ;-)
I still can not solve my problem with jsonreference modes. I start think about changing architecture of database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it. Again. StackOverFlow gives me more motivation than problem :D

So, after 3 long day of thinking every hour about my problem, i almost decline deserialization to json and take a decision do not user json in this case, but than i think about jsonidentity of class and this is my solution.

Using JsonIdentityInfo, every time Jackson serialises your object, it will add an id (in my case it is uuid) to it, so that it won't scan it again always.

**UPDATE ASNWER (i removed code previous version of answer for shortener of answer):**
Unfortunately, when i test my solution in different cases i've found, that it is working for only first version of json identity. So first "scan" completely work like a charm, but instead second scan i got an ID of jsonidentity instead of object. This is gives me understanding, that i need my own serialization logic where i can controler depth of recursion. And i wrote it. I can show only skeleton of custom json serializator because logic of serialization is easy and depends on class structure.

```
public class JsonUserSerializer extends JsonSerializer<User> {
        @Override
        public void serialize(User o, JsonGenerator jsonGen, SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
                throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            // ... logic of json generation
            Field[] userClassFields = o.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            // ... logic of json generation
        }

        @Override
        public Class<User> handledType() {
            return User.class;
        }
    }
```

The main problem which i have to solved while working on code it is naming of fields. Because json structure it is: "name":"value" - and in my case name - it is fieldName. But hardcode it is not my way. Than i've found solution to get ALL fields of class it is `o.getClass().getDeclaredFields()`and than looking needs field by index. I think it is not the best solution, but i did not find out other for a one hour (if you know other way - write a comment - i will commend author for it).

Forget to show how to use custom JsonSerialiser which specified for specific class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@JsonSerialize(using = JsonUserSerializer.class)
public class User implements Serializable {
    // a lot of fields and getter, and setters
}
```