# SQL Query to Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate

Can someone please help me translate this MySQL Query to Hibernate.

```
select F1.FighterName, F2.FighterName
            from Fight N 
                inner join Fighter F1 on N.Fighter1=F1.idFighter
                inner join Fighter F2 on N.Fighter2=F2.idFighter
```

Your help shall be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Below [HQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) assumes that your Fighter has 1-N association to Fight and N-N association to itself. See following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656113/hibernate-many-to-many-association-with-the-same-entity) to make many to many association to same table in hibernate.

```
 select F1.FighterName, F2.FighterName
 from Fighter F1 
 inner join Fighter F2
```